# How to use a layout statically in Laravel?

Tags: php, css, layout, laravel

As an admin I can create pages (don't think I have to paste my `adminpagescontroller` here, because you understand the logic). What I'm getting stuck on, is selecting, but especially using the layout that will be used for the page.

i.e. I have three layouts:

- page with left sidebar
- page with right sidebar
- page with full-width (no sidebars)

And i.e. I want to create a salespage or so, which uses the layouts "page with full-width". How can I call this in my view?

Now all my views begin with `@extends('layouts.path.file')` <--- I need that to be filled in by the database, if you know what I mean.

Comment: If you think a question is off-topic here, then - err - don't do it! If you are not sure, select the appropriate chatroom and ask in there. That said, this is a specific, directed question, so I think it is OK.

Comment: @halfer my last option is always go to SO if there's nothing else on the web that can help me. First check previous/related questions etc. and than ask the question if i can't find anything.

Comment: That's great - if you've done prior research, I don't think questions _have_ to feature code. I think there's a (quite good) rule that most questions ought to have code, though, since questions that don't have code are usually "not programming enough" for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use a view composer to define the current layout to be used. View composers set variables that can be used by all your views ('*') or just some ('users.profile', 'admin.profile'), so this is an example of using a user specific layout:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('userLayout', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->layout : 'main');
});
```

And in your view you just have to:

```
@extends('layouts.'.$userLayout);
```

If you just need to select a page on your controller, you can pass a layout to it:

```
return View::make('myview')->with('layout', 'front.main');
```

And use it in your view:

```
@extends('layouts.'.$layout);
```

And if you have it on a table, you can just pass it on:

```
$layout = Pages::first()->layout;

return View::make('myview')->with('layout', $layout);
```

Or do the same in your composer

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $layout = Pages::first()->layout;

    $view->with('layout', $layout);
});
```

A lot of people like to set the layout in controller too, so you could in your controller do:

```
public function showProfile()
{
    $this->layout = Pages::first()->layout;

    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
}
```

And your views doesn't have to @extend a layout anymore, because you are already telling them which layout to use.

Comment: Ok, i guess i understand that. But than my question is. How can i pass this through when creating a page? i.e. my pages table has a column 'layout' and its value is 'layouts.front.main', how can i than use it?

PS, i'm sorry i don't know the right terms for this.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understood it. You say you have a pages table, but how do you get records from that table? Had to guess, so added some more ways of doing it. And about your comment, that's exactly why StackOverflow asks people to show code, because the guessing game sometimes just doesn't help anyone.

Comment: `$layout = Pages::first()->layout;

return View::make('myview')->with('layout', $layout);` and in view, `@extends($layout);` A VERY bad design i must say.

Comment: Your last edit helped me a lot :)  

I know that's why SO asks people to show code, but i've been trying to find anything about this on the internet, but i couldn't find the right stuff. If i pasted some code, that wouldn't help you or other SO'ers, since it wouldn't make sense of what i want. 

Next time i'll try to write some code first. Thanks anyways @antonio!

Comment: As itachi beautifully said, some of this is bad designed. I'm not sure if you should be doing thing the way you are, but I'm trying to answer and put you in some track, so you can understand Laravel and how things work on it and not really trying to achieve a great design here. And, also, this is not really a forum for design problems, but coding problems. And I'm glad it's helping already. :)

Comment: Don't worry, i won't use that code like that :) I edited your last edit to my needs. I can show you how i'm using it but that will be a long paste. All that matters is that it's working ;p